# Using of sum withinin group_concat

Tags: sqlite

Let's say i have a table, Product. This contains several Products with different vatpercentages and vatprices:

### Product

```
ArticleId | Price | VatPercentage | VatPrice
(integer) (numeric)   (varchar)    (numeric)
--------------------------------------------
    1       100     25.0000000000     25 
    2        80     25.0000000000     20 
    3        50      8.0000000000     4 
    4        70      8.0000000000     5.6 
    5        20           0           0
    0
```

Now i need to build strings using Group_concat and sum prices by vatpercentage where VatPrice is not 0 and price is not 0.

**The result i want back in this case:**

```
{a}25{b}45 SEK{c}{a}8{b}9.6 SEK{c}
```

**The code i've tried:**

```
select 
group_concat('{a}' || 
CAST(VatPercentage as integer) ||
'{b}' || SUM(VatPrice) || 
' SEK' || '{c}','') 
FROM Product 
group by VatPercentage
having Count(Price) > 0
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fbf38/1)

Thanks on forehand

Comment: I don't think you need `GROUP_CONCAT``. Why doesn't the second line of the sample output have a `VatPrice:` label?

Comment: In my case i really need to do this with Group concat due do limitations in a script language.

Comment: Why doesn't your sample result have `VatPercentage: 0% VatPrice; 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the regular concatenation in a subquery, then use `GROUP_CONCAT` in an outer query, because you can't use one aggregation function in the arguments to another.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Result, '|') Results
FROM (
    SELECT 'VatPercentage:' || CAST(VatPercentage AS INTEGER) || '% VatPrice: '
        || SUM(VatPrice) Result
    FROM Product
    WHERE VatPercentage != '0'
    GROUP BY VatPercentage) x
```

You also don't need the `HAVING` clause. That just excludes results where all the `Price` values are `NULL`. But your sample result is skipping rows where `VatPercentage` is zero, so I've put that in the `WHERE` clause.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c60e5/7)

Comment: Thanks for your input. In my case i really need to do this with Group_concat else i will only get one row due to limitations in a script language.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. GROUP_CONCAT is for getting multiple input rows concatenated into the output row. Your sample output doesn't have anything like that.

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation, yes it need to be a concatinated string.

Comment: Concatenation is done with `||`. `GROUP_CONCAT` is for concatenating multiple rows, but that's not what you're doing. You're combining the rows with `SUM`, not concatenation.

Comment: In my case i need to merge multiple rows into one row due to limitations. Therefore i need to use Group_concat.

Comment: `SUM` already merges multiple rows into one row. Anyway, you have my answer. The second version uses `GROUP_CONCAT`, even though there's nothing to concatenate.

Comment: Maybe you should update the question to explain these "limitations" you keep referring to.

Comment: Now i've updated my post of the output i need to have back from sqlite: {a}25{b}45 SEK{c}{a}8{b}9.6 SEK{c}

Comment: Just change the literal strings in the concatenation. What's the problem?

Comment: Ahh saaw your new answer now. :) Thanks a lot man! Worked perfectly.

Comment: Is it possible to even join Another table? referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262040/how-to-use-sum-and-joins-within-group-concat  Thanks again :)