# How to use sum and joins within group_concat

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables, CustomerCategories and Articles. Both tables have a column called VatPercentage and VatPrice.

**Scenarios:**

- In case of same vatpercentage exists in both tables i want to sum the vatprice from both tables and add it to the string.
- In case of vatpercentage only exists in CustomerCategories table i want to sum the vatprice from here and add it to the string.
- In case of vatpercentage only exists in Articles table i want to sum the vatprice from here and add it to the string.

**Example tables:**

**Articles:**

```
ArticleId       TotalPrice      VatPercentage    VatPrice
1                   100         25.0000000000    25
2                   80          25.0000000000    20
3                   50          8.0000000000     4
4                   70          8.0000000000     5.6
5                   20          0                0
6                   0           0                0
```

**CustomerCategories:**

```
CustomerCategoryId  TotalPrice  VatPercentage   VatPrice
2                   163         8.0000000000    13
2                   163         13.0000000000   13
2                   163         0               0
2                   150         25.0000000000   37.5
```

The result i want back from the Query in this case:

```
{esc}{40h}25 %{esc}{41h}82.5 NOK{lf}{esc}{40h}8 %{esc}{41h}22.6 NOK{lf}{esc}{40h}13 %{esc}{41h}13 NOK{lf}
```

The code i've trying without any positive results is:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Result, '|') Results
FROM (
   select case when cc.VatPercentage = a.VatPercentage 
   then
   SELECT '{esc}{40}' || CAST(cc.VatPercentage AS INTEGER) || '% ' ||
           (SUM(cc.VatPrice) + SUM(a.VatPrice)) || ' NOK' || '{lf}' Result    end
else
   (
     case when cc.VatPercentage <> a.VatPercentage
       then 
       SELECT '{esc}{40}' || CAST(cc.VatPercentage AS INTEGER) || '% ' ||
           (SUM(cc.VatPrice) + SUM(a.VatPrice)) || ' NOK' || '{lf}' ||
           SELECT '{esc}{40}' || CAST(a.VatPercentage AS INTEGER) || '% ' ||
           (SUM(a.VatPrice)) || ' NOK' || '{lf}' Result 
      end
   )
FROM CustomerCategories cc
LEFT JOIN Articles a
  on cc.VatPercentage = a.VatPercentage
WHERE 
  cc.VatPercentage != '0' 
  AND a.VatPercentage != '0'
  AND cc.TotalPrice != '0'
  AND a.TotalPrice != '0'
  GROUP BY 
    cc.VatPercentage OR a.VatPercentage) x
```

Help would be appreciated.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/92dfa/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [combine](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) both tables:

```
SELECT VatPercentage, VatPrice FROM CustomerCategories
UNION ALL
SELECT VatPercentage, VatPrice FROM Articles
```

```
VatPercentage   VatPrice
8.0000000000    13
13.0000000000   13
0               0
25.0000000000   37.5
25.0000000000   25
25.0000000000   20
8.0000000000    4
8.0000000000    5.6
0               0
0               0
```

Then do a simple GROUP BY over that:

```
SELECT VatPercentage,
       SUM(VatPrice) AS PriceSum
FROM (SELECT VatPercentage, VatPrice FROM CustomerCategories
      UNION ALL
      SELECT VatPercentage, VatPrice FROM Articles)
WHERE VatPercentage != '0'
GROUP BY VatPercentage
```

Then do the escape characters mess over the result of that:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('{esc}{40h}' || VatPercentage || ' %' ||
                    '{esc}{41h}' || VatPrice      || ' NOK{lf}',
                    '')
FROM (SELECT VatPercentage,
             SUM(VatPrice) AS PriceSum
      FROM (SELECT VatPercentage, VatPrice FROM CustomerCategories
            UNION ALL
            SELECT VatPercentage, VatPrice FROM Articles)
      WHERE VatPercentage != '0'
      GROUP BY VatPercentage)
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) Is it possible to make it in ascending order by ? i've tried to add order by after the Group by but it doesnt sort.

Comment: Strings compare lexicographically, not like numbers.